# "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead."

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I am trying to decode data from `Firestore` to json format but got that error.

This is model class

```
class UserModel : Codable{


var email: String?
var name: String?

var roles: [Roles]?

  init(email: String, name: String, roles: [Roles]) {
    self.email = email
    self.name = name

    self.roles = roles
  }

 }
```

This is Roles struct

```
struct Roles: Codable {

var role: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
    case role = "student"


}
```

}

I have checked some answers from stackoverflow but nothing help me.

This is how I decode it:

```
extension DocumentSnapshot {

func decode<T: Decodable>(as objectType: T.Type, includingId: Bool = true) throws  -> T {

    var documentJson = data()
    if includingId {

        documentJson?["id"] = documentID
    }

    let documentData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: documentJson ?? "null", options: [])
    let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(objectType, from: documentData)

    return decodedObject
}
```

}

This is my Json file

```
{
  name: "pisal",
  email: "email@gmail.com",
  roles: [
     myrole : "student"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show your json.

Comment: Why are you trying to use JSONSerialization _and_ JSONDecoder? That makes no sense.

Comment: @matt Then should I remove JSONSerialization.data ??

Comment: Your json and your structs do not resemble one another in any way.

Comment: @matt I have updated model class. Is it okay?

Comment: I’ve no idea. Your json is invalid. Please show your real json.